# MVC-Unit test - ViewEngines

Tags: unit-testing, model-view-controller

Hey, 
I'm working with mvc I have to write unit test for function that contains

```
var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, partialPath);
```

and my test fails on this part : "The RouteData must contain an item named 'controller' with a non-empty string value."How can I make face object for this?
thx

Answer (score 4):

add that for controller

```
 var routeData = new RouteData();
 routeData.Values.Add("controller", "someName");
 routeData.Values.Add("action", "someAction");
```